# What's the difference between a class variable and a parameter in a constructor?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, class-variables

I am asking this in response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19759753/2776866).

I'm using an example of `Variable` and `Var`- **edit** Pls note I am asking where to use `Var` or `Variable`:

```
Class NewClass {

    private  String Variable = "";

    Public Class (String Var)
    {
        NewClass.Var = Variable;
    }
}
```

*OR*

```
    private  String Variable = "";

    Public Class (String Variable)
    {
        NewClass.Variable = Var; // OR WHATEVER OTHER COMBINATIONS IT MAY BE.
    }
}
```

Which ones are the class variables,  how does this differ from the parameters and which goes where?

**edit**

I should add, as this was in the linked answer, but it seems people haven't looked at it:

> It's particularly confusing because the parameters to the function
>   have exactly the same names as the class variables, but Patient.ptNo
>   is not the same variable as the parameter ptNo. (Actually,
>   Patient.ptNo should be this.ptNo, because it belongs to this
>   particular instance of the class. Patient.ptNo would refer to a single
>   value that's common to all objects of type Patient.)

So when people say `this.Variable = Variable` I am still confused about what is what.

Comment: I like your new username -- or should I say userphrase :-)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The variable's name doesn't matter: `Var` and `Variable` are the same to the compiler. The only exceptions are if it's a reserved word in Java (none of `Var`, `var`, `Variable`, `variable` or any other variant on the capitalization are), in which case it won't compile at all.

Comment: @yshavit Note that OP has fixed Variable as the name of the instance variable and is asking about the variations in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class variable is the one defined by the class as a `static` field, and the parameter is the one defined by the method. It's just that simple. There are also instance variables (defined at the class level but not static) and local variables (defined within a method, but not as input parameters).

```
public class Foo {
    private static String someName; // this is a class variable
    private String someOtherName; // this is an instance variable

    public Foo(String anotherName) { // anotherName is a constructor parameter
        int yetAnother = 1; // yetAnother is a local variable
        someOtherName = "foo"; // assign a value to someOtherName
    }
```

These two variables are *completely* distinct. They don't even have to have the same type! The only complication in your example is that both variables happen to have the same name. When that happens, the compiler will favor the constructor parameter (or method parameter, or local variable) over the class variable. In order to "force" it to use the class variable, you prefix it with `this.`.

The thing to keep in mind is that the two variables are totally separate, regardless of their names.

So this:

```
class NewClass {

    private  String Variable = "";

    Public NewClass (String Variable)
    {
        NewClass.Variable = Variable;
    }
}
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
class NewClass {

    private  String Variable = "";

    Public NewClass (String someOtherVariableName)
    {
        NewClass.Variable = someOtherVariableName;
    }
}
```

... and it's also exactly the same as this:

```
class NewClass {

    private  String Variable = "";

    Public NewClass (String Var)
    {
        NewClass.Variable = Var;
    }
}
```

The convention of using the same name for a parameter as for the class variable just means you don't have to come up with pointless variants on the variable name.

Comment: `NewClass.Variable = Var;` the compiler will complian since `Variable` not static

Answer (score 3):

No problem of using variable as your constructor parameter as it is the local variable for your constructor.

```
class NewClass {

    private  String Variable = "";

    Public NewClass (String Variable)
    {
        this.Variable = Variable;
    }
}

                       or

class NewClass {

    private  String Variable = "";

    Public NewClass (String Var)
    {
        this.Variable = Var;
    }
}
```

both are fine.

`this.Variable` denotes the current objects variable.

Try reading naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

`this.Variable` would refer to the `Variable` field of the class and just `Variable` would be the parameter passed to the constructor.

`private  String Variable = "";` - This is not static

Therefore your constructor would look liek

```
public NewClass(String Var/iable) {
    this.Variable = Variable; // this must be used, where this.Variable is the class variable and just Variable is the constructor parameter.
}
```

Note: You have used the `ClassName.fieldName` which is allowed only for static fields of the class. It should be `this.fieldName` instead, if the `Variable` is not `static`. Also, `Public` shouldn't be in caps, the constructor name should be the Class name. The keyword `class` should be in small and not `Class`.

In case you want to use the way you've put in your code, the `Variable` in the class should be static. Something like this

```
private static String Variable = "";
public NewClass(String Var/iable) {
    NewClass.Variable = Variable; // Since Variable is static now, you use the classname to access the static field.
}
```

*Edit:* It is absolutely okay to use the same name, as long as you can differentiate them both. In this case, `this.Variable` would mean the class variable and just `Variable` would refer to the parameter which was passed to constructor while creating an instance of this class.

```
class Variable = Variable passed to the constructor; // This is what the below statement means
this.Variable = Variable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class NewClass {

private  String variable = "";

public NewClass (String variable)
{
    this.variable = variable;
}
}
```

this.variable refers to current object instance.
Please follow naming conventions